# Search user by username and redirect to the user page in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I am working on a Django project, and now I am building a search form with which I can look up users by their id. 
In the search page template, I have this:

```
<form action="??" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<ul><p>User ID<input type="text" name="uid" size="20" maxlength="40"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p></ul></form>
```

In views.py:

```
def user_by_id(request, uid):
    get_user_by_id = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    template = loader.get_template('user_search_result.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'q1': get_user_by_id,
    })

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Right now I have individual pages for users ready, that have the url /users/uid(pk). What should I choose for the form action in the template that I left as ?? above? Also, what would I need to write in urls.py?

My main urls.py is:

```
url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace="users"))
```

and then users/urls.py for individual profile pages is:

```
url(r'^(?P<uid>\d+)/$', views.profile_page, name='profile_page')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the result of a form in the URL. The form will send it as part of the GET or POST variables, so your view needs to get it from there rather than from a URL parameter.

So, your view needs to be:

```
def user_by_id(request):
    uid = request.GET['uid']
    ...etc...
```

and your urls.py is

```
url(r'^user_by_id/$', user_by_id, name="user_by_id")
```

and your form is:

```
<form action="{% url 'user_by_id' %}" method="GET">
```

(note I've changed the method from POST to GET, because you're not changing information in the database, you're simply requesting to view something).

Comment: hey @daniel, thank you for your answer. I am getting this error though: NoReverseMatch at /users/search/
Reverse for 'user_by_id' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. Do you know what I should do about it?

Comment: What does your urls.py look like now?

Comment: I used url(r'^user_by_id/$', user_by_id, name="user_by_id") like you commented.

Comment: And that's in your main urls.py? You should probably post that whole file (in an edit to the question itself).

Comment: I just did. Thanks again.

Comment: You're using a namespace to include your user urls.py, so you should do "users:user_by_id" in the URL tag.